# Do we have any function to get filtering of data in R or Python

Tags: python, r

I am new to R and i am unable to figure it out how to filter the data which as require

Below is the data with (326 rows and 6 columns)

[DataSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aENr8.png)

Here is the small example:

```
Author,Commenid,Parentid,Submissionid Score Stance
User1 ,  333c ,    222b ,   111b     , 10 ,  Positive      
User2 ,  444c ,    333c ,    5hdc    , 15 ,  Neutral
User3 ,  222b ,    555d ,    23er    , 20 ,  Negative
User4 ,  555d ,    666f ,    111b    , 11 ,  Positive
```

here user1 means, he had replied to the user2

```
 user3 had replied to user1  
 user4 had replied to user3
```

I want to filter as users who have same commentid and parentid  ,For above example we will get 
data filtered as

```
Author     Score   Stance         Reply    Score  Stance
User2      15      Neutral          User1      10    Positive 
User1      10      Positive         User3      20    Negative 
User3      20     Negative         User4      11    Positive
```

I tried a lot and I am not able to figure it out, can anyone help me how we can do it exactly(R or Python).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your sample output. User1 has Commenid 333c, and User2 has the same Parentid, 333c. Why is User2 not included in the output?

Comment: Can you please use `dput` of the data in `R`

Comment: @gregor-thomas , Sorry i have not explained the output correctly it results the pair of the author who replied to the other author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R answer.
First `match` columns `Commenid` with `Parentid`. Create a data set with the `Author` column and a `Reply` column of the authors matched before. Keep all rows with no `NA` values and join (`merge`) with the original data to have the other columns.

```
i <- with(df1, match(Commenid, Parentid))
res <- data.frame(Author = df1$Author, Reply = df1$Author[i])
res <- res[complete.cases(res), ]  
merge(res, df1)
#  Author Reply Commenid Parentid Submissionid
#1  User1 User2     333c     222b         111b
#2  User3 User1     222b     555d         23er
#3  User4 User3     555d     666f         111b
```

A [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) solution could be

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(i = match(Commenid, Parentid),
         Reply = Author[i]) %>%
  filter(!is.na(i)) %>%
  select(Author, Reply, everything(vars = -i))
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.csv(text = "
Author,Commenid,Parentid,Submissionid  
User1 ,  333c ,    222b ,   111b            
User2 ,  444c ,    333c ,    5hdc   
User3 ,  222b ,    555d ,    23er   
User4 ,  555d ,    666f ,    111b                
")
df1[] <- lapply(df1, trimws)
```

## Edit

With the new data and problem described in comments, here is a `dplyr` solution. After what is basically the same as above, it joins the result with the original data set and reorders the columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  mutate(i = match(Commenid, Parentid),
         Reply = Author[i]) %>%
  filter(!is.na(i)) %>%
  select(-i) %>%
  select(Author, Score, Stance, Reply, everything()) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% select(Author, Score, Stance), by = c("Reply" = "Author")) %>%
  select(-matches("id$"), everything(), matches("id$"))
```

**New data**

```
df2 <- read.csv(text = "
Author,Commenid,Parentid,Submissionid, Score, Stance
User1 ,  333c ,    222b ,   111b     , 10 ,  Positive      
User2 ,  444c ,    333c ,    5hdc    , 15 ,  Neutral
User3 ,  222b ,    555d ,    23er    , 20 ,  Negative
User4 ,  555d ,    666f ,    111b    , 11 ,  Positive
")
names(df1) <- trimws(names(df1))
df1[] <- lapply(df1, trimws)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution,  After apply on my dataset, i got author and reply pairs..       
I have one more question - if the user as individual weights can we get that weights has  well. For example  user1 - weight1 - user2 - weight2  (Weights are different to each other)

Comment: @YogeshKumar Probably yes, that would be possible but we need to see an example data set. Can you edit the question with an example of what you want?

Comment: I have updated the dataset and the required output parameters. Please let me know if anything is not clear. Thank You so much for your helping hands

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each user to other users , and if the `commentid` equals `parentid` then you can print it , here is how you can do it in Python :

```
for u1 in dataset :
    for u2 in dataset :
        if u1['parentid'] == u2['commentid'] :
           print( u1['Author'],' had comment of ',u2['Author'] )
```